# SKReceiptRefreshRequest asking password everytime

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am using `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` to validate the receipt from the server. The problem is it is asking me every time password prompt. Can anyone help suggest me a better way to validate the user receipt

Here's what I am doing (i am using `refreshReceipt` when the app starts)

```
- (void)refreshReceipt {
    SKReceiptRefreshRequest *refresh = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:nil];
    refresh.delegate = self;
    [refresh start];
}

- (void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest *)request API_AVAILABLE(ios(3.0), macos(10.7)) {
    if ([request isKindOfClass:[SKReceiptRefreshRequest class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Got a new receipt...");
        [self verifyReceipt:self.loadingView :NO :^{

        } :^{
            [app_delegate jumpToLogin];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)verifyReceipt :(UIView *)view1 :(BOOL)showHUD : (void (^)(void)) complete : (void (^)(void)) incomplete
{
    if (showHUD) {
        [UtilityManager showHUD:view1];
    }

    /* Load the receipt from the app bundle. */

    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];

    if (!receipt) {
        /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */
        [UtilityManager hideHUD:view1];
        incomplete();
        return;
    }

    /* Create the JSON object that describes the request */
    NSError *error;

    // Verify the recipt
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case it's asking for a password because sandbox receipt is missing on your device. It's trying to refresh existing receipt, but can't find it. So it's going to get a fresh receipt, that is why it's asking for a password.

In production (when the app is downloaded from the App Store) there will always be a receipt, so it won't require a password.

And why are you using `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`? It's only required for "Restore purchases" button.

Here is article from our blog: https://blog.apphud.com/receipt-validation/

Comment: So it means it will not ask in the production environment?

Comment: @MayankPatel if the app is downloaded from the App Store, it will not ask for a password after `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` call.

Comment: ok got it and i am using this because i am using auto-renew subscription and i don't want to use restore purchase and i am not using restore purchase in the app based on concept

Comment: @apphud so let’s say I am singing out from the device for the iTunes and I am checking there to validate if it’s working or not then ?

Comment: @ArbazShaikh no, it will not ask if you signed out but receipt exists.

Comment: @MayankPatel if you don't use restore purchases, you should have your server then. Or you can use subscription server as a service like ours. Link in bio.

Comment: @apphud then it will going to be wrong as if some one has bought and lets say he is changing the phone and the phone is in some one other login then it will not ask then?

Comment: @apphud So what i need to do is when app opens then i need to restore it once restore is done then i need to call verify receipt api is that correct?

Comment: What happens when the user cancels a non auto-renewable subscription?
The only way to get the updated receipt data for a non auto-renewable subscription is by calling SKReceiptRefreshRequest.
  
 "latest_receipt_info" exists only for receipts that contain auto-renewable subscriptions.

Comment: @Vamsy there is also in_app array for other types of purchases

Comment: @apphud The receipt_data that is saved when a purchase is made in the device, only have the purchase details. "in_app" has a list of transaction details. 
The initial receipt will not have cancellation_date for the transaction. 
The only was to get cancellation_date for non auto-renewable subscription is by calling SKReceiptRefreshRequest from the code.

Comment: @apphud > "In production (when the app is downloaded from the App Store) there will always be a receipt, so it won't require a password." -- So if a user buys a subscription on one device, then downloads the app on another device, that app will come from the App Store with a receipt, and that receipt will have the purchase from the previous device?

Answer (score 0):

The receipt_data that is saved when a purchase is made in the device, only have the purchase details. "in_app" has a list of transaction details. The initial receipt will not have cancellation_date for the transaction.

The only was to get cancellation_date for non auto-renewable subscription is by calling SKReceiptRefreshRequest from the code.

It is very inconvenient for the user to enter their password every single time we try to update the receipt. I'm calling SKReceiptRefreshRequest once a week to check for the receipt updates.

I have verified the same with Apple as well by creating a  Technical Support Incidents. They don't have a better way to solve this.