# Under what circumstances might an App Store receipt be missing or invalid?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

In the [SKReceiptRefreshRequest docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skreceiptrefreshrequest?language=objc) it says:

> Use this API to request a new receipt if the receipt is invalid or missing.

When would the receipt be missing or invalid?

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59626035/741970) that says apps downloaded from the App Store come with a receipt. Is this correct? And if so, does this receipt contain all the IAPs the user made on other devices?

Answer (score 0):

Debug builds and apps installed via TestFlight do not necessarily contain a receipt.

The receipt can be somewhat invalid when the user made a purchase on another device or gained access via family sharing.

Comment: Thank you Paul. What does “somewhat invalid” mean? Do you know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, I have no idea. The App Store and all that syncing of purchases between users and their devices is a very complex system and therefore there is a high chance for hiccups.